# Anyway to convert a static array to a dynamic array?

Tags: c#, .net

Int[] test = new int[7]

how to change test to a dynamic array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no real notion of a stack allocated "static" array in C# (ignoring unsafe context and `stackalloc`). What you just wrote is a dynamic array. It's an object created at runtime on the managed heap. The size can be an expression or variable. For instance:

```
int[] a = new int[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())];
```

If by dynamic array, you mean an array you can resize easily (like `vector` in C++), you should use `List<T>`:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>();
a.Add(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to change it to a `List<int>`? If that were the case:

```
int[] test = new int[7];

List<int> testList = new List(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this can be achieved by using the `ToList()` extension method (you will need to import the `System.Linq` namespace). Here is an example:

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IList<int> numbersDynamic = numbers.ToList();
```

That would give you a list class that you can manipulate as needed.

Comment: any difference between this and SnOrfus?

Comment: Same result, different approach.